# Generating random noise in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, gaussian, noise

When I add Gaussian noise to an array shouldnt the histogram be Gaussian? Although the noise is random, the distribution should be gaussian right? That is not what I get.

```
A=zeros(10);
A=imnoise(A,'gaussian');
imhist(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things could be going on:

1. You don't have enough of a sample size, or
2. The default mean of imnoise with gaussian distribution is 0, meaning you're only seeing the right half of the bell curve.

Try

```
imhist(imnoise(zeros(1000), 'gaussian', 0.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code is doing:

```
A = zeros(10);

mu = 0; sd = 0.1;                 %# mean, std dev
B = A + randn(size(A))*sd + mu;   %# add gaussian noise

B = max(0,min(B,1));              %# make sure that 0 <= B <= 1

imhist(B)                         %# intensities histogram
```

can you see where the problem is? (Hint: RANDN returns number `~N(0,1)`, thus the resulting added noise is `~N(mu,sd)`)

---

Perhaps what you are trying to do is:

```
hist( randn(1000,1) )
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 0):

imnoise() is a function that can be applied to *images*,  not plain arrays.
Maybe you can look into the randn() function, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might not see a bell-curve with a sampling frame of only 10.

See the central limit theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

I would try increasing the sampling frame to something much larger.

---

**Reference**:

Law of Large Numbers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers